# is there a way to turn off warnings for undeclared methods in xcode 4.x ( < 4.3 )

Tags: xcode

I am working on a project with mountain lion, and I have only declared public methods, but my other team member is on snow leopard with 4.2-- and she gets a million warnings from my lack of declaring "private methods".  Before I spend time updating all the .h files, I thougth I'd ask here if there's a simple build setting that will make it not complain about that... ?

Comment: If the class has no private members, they are simply not usable for anyone else. You can't call something that's not there.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode's preferences you could disable "Show live issues" and enable "continue building after errors."

[image]